# IEnumerable and yield return

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, nunit, mstest

My unit tests are doing something very strange when I call a method of a generic base type. I have tried both NUnit and MSTest with the same result. This is how the code is organized:

```
public class MyStub {}

public class EnumerableGenerator
{
     public bool GotMyStubs;

     public IEnumerable<MyStub> GetMyStubs()
     {
         GotMyStubs = true;
         yield return new MyStub();
     }
}
public class ConsoleRunner
{
public void Main(string args[])
{
     EnumerableGenerator gen = new EnumerableGenerator();
     gen.GotMyStubs = false;
     var myStubs = gen.GetMyStubs();
     if  (!gen.GotMyStubs)
         return 1;
} 
}
```

The test fails obviously. The strange part is that the code functions fine when I'm integration testing it. It only breaks in the unit test. I cannot step into GetMyStubs at all. Break points within the method do not break either. I have turned on breaking for all exceptions being thrown by the CLR and this yields nothing as well.

I examined the type returned by GetMyStubs and the type's full name looks like this:

[MyNamespace.EnumerableGenerator2+`<GetMyStubs>`d__8[[MyNamespace.MyStub, MyNamespace, Version=7.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Now when I look at my code coverage numbers (through MSTest) I notice that there is a EnumerableGenerator.d__8 entry.

Has anyone seen something like this? I'm completely lost....

Comment: Simplified the code example to illustrate the real issue and changed the name to match more closely.

Comment: Right - yes, that definitely explains why it's failing.

Comment: I get this one quite frequently. Here are my articles on it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/05/psychic-debugging-part-one.aspx

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/06/psychic-debugging-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've given won't even compile - there isn't a `Count` property on `IEnumerable<T>`. There's a `Count()` *extension method* - is that what you meant?

I strongly suspect that `MyMethod()` doesn't *really* look like that either. I suspect it actually uses `yield return` to return the items... at which point the type's full name would make sense, as it's a state machine generated for you by the iterator block.

Assuming that's the case, when you call `MyMethod()`, that won't execute any of your code. It will create the state machine and return it. When you start iterating over it, *then* it will start executing your code... and that's when I'd expect break points to be hit.

Could you provide a short but complete example (using NUnit if necessary, but a console app would be ideal) of it failing?

Comment: Yup you were right about the extension method. That is what I meant. And again you were right about the yield return. I've definitely learned something about that today. I'll update the example above to more clearly illustrate the code.